# Question involving position vectors

Tags: vectors

The points A, B, C and D have position vectors **a**, **b**, **4b** and *k*(**a - b**) respectively. Find the value of *k* when

(a) **AD** is parallel to **b**

(b) **BD** is parallel to **a**

(c) **CD** is parallel to **a + b**

(d) A, C and D are collinear.

I know that **AD** parallel to **b** means **d - a** = m**b**, where m is some constant but I cannot see my way to finding *k*.

The answer to (a) is 1 but I cannot see how this was arrived at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector $\vec{AD}$ is given by $\vec{D} - \vec{A}$

$$\vec{AD} = k(\vec{a}-\vec{b}) - \vec{a} = (k-1)\vec{a} - k\vec{b}$$

Now, since $\vec{AD}$ is parallel to $b$, either

1. $\vec{a} || \vec{b}$
2. $k = 1$ so that the $\vec{a}$ term vanishes

Since no condition is given on $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ that's all you can say

Comment: If $\vec AD$ is parallel to b why does that imply a is parallel to b?  i.e. ($\vec a || \vec b$)?